# Android (ndk) multicast lock is acquired but can't receive UDP broadcast packets

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, broadcast, multicast

I created and acquired multicast, wifi and wake locks and also set the SO_BROADCAST socket option but still can't receive UDP broadcast packets on android devices.

Project is written in C and uses JNI for creating locks.

```
void android_main(struct android_app* app) {
    JavaVM* vm = app->activity->vm;
    JNIEnv* env = app->activity->env;
    (*vm)->AttachCurrentThread(vm, &env, NULL);
    ANativeActivity* activity = app->activity;
    jmethodID jtmID;

    jclass jNativeClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, activity->clazz);
    jtmID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, jNativeClass, "getApplication", "()Landroid/app/Application;");
    jobject jNativeApplication = (jobject)(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, activity->clazz, jtmID);
    jtmID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, jNativeApplication), "getApplicationContext", "()Landroid/content/Context;");
    jobject jNativeContext = (jobject)(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, jNativeApplication, jtmID);
    jfieldID jNativeWIFI_SERVICE_fid = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env, (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, jNativeContext), "WIFI_SERVICE", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring jNativeSFID_jstr = (jstring)(*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env, (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/content/Context"), jNativeWIFI_SERVICE_fid);
    jstring wifiLockjStr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "PROJECT");

    jtmID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/content/Context"), "getSystemService", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    jobject jSystemService = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, jNativeContext, jtmID, jNativeSFID_jstr);

    jclass jWMClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/net/wifi/WifiManager");
    jclass jWMMLClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/net/wifi/WifiManager$MulticastLock");
    jtmID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, jWMClass, "createMulticastLock", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/net/wifi/WifiManager$MulticastLock;");
    jobject jMCObj = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, jSystemService, jtmID, wifiLockjStr);

    jtmID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, jWMMLClass, "setReferenceCounted", "(Z)V");
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, jMCObj, jtmID, 0);

    jtmID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, jWMMLClass, "acquire", "()V");
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, jMCObj, jtmID);
    jtmID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, jWMMLClass, "isHeld", "()Z");
    jboolean isheld = (*env)->CallBooleanMethod(env, jMCObj, jtmID);
    if (isheld) {
        printf("MulticastLock acquired\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("MulticastLock is not acquired\n");
    }
   ... (Create and set socket then start listening)
}
```

isheld value is true but multicast lock doesn't seem to work. After this code block udp socket is created for broadcast and socket option SO_BROADCAST is set. Socket part is cross platform and can receive broadcast messages on windows,linux,etc. but can not on android.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are requesting the following two permissions in your Android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
```

I had the same issue, and adding them fixed it for me.